# Command to clear all breakpoints in VSCode (as in visual studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In visual studio you can `Ctrl+Shift+F9` to clear all breakpoints.
Is there a similar function in VsCode?
I couldn't find any good answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is an unbound command `workbench.debug.viewlet.action.removeAllBreakpoints` that you could set to your own keybinding.

```
{
  "key": "alt+b",
  "command": "workbench.debug.viewlet.action.removeAllBreakpoints"
},
```

In the Keyboard Shortcuts just search for `breakpoint` and various commands come up.

And in the Breakpoints panel viewlet hover over one of the icons to see that it will "Remove all breakpoints"

[image]

Comment: +1 for the screenshot showing exactly what to click. So many answers about VS Code assume everyone knows where the settings off. But it's unintuitive, especially for newbies.

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to goto Run -> Remove all breakpoints.

[VSCode Remove all breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PRyj.png)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette -> Search for "Remove All Breakpoints"

[image]