# How to remove the multiple debugging red dots breakpoints from the vscode editor?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, debugging

How can I remove the multiple debugging red dots from the vscode 1.77.3 editor?

[image]

Comment: click on it or open up the debug panel and clear them there

Comment: I still want the breakpoint on the left just not in the editor view, the one right of "this."

Comment: if you have multiple statements on a line you need to know where the breakpoint is

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59320880/11107541

Comment: If I understand correctly, you do **not** want to _remove the breakpoint_, but rather you object to the _inline breakpoint indicator_ and would prefer that the breakpoint were only indicated by the margin indicator and **not** by an inline indicator.  Is that right?

Comment: @Wyck, that is correct

Comment: Does disabling the setting `Debug: Show Inline Breakpoint Candidates` do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

[Run or Debug tab] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWbuW.png

You can see the All exceptions and Uncaught exceptions when you switch to the run and debug tab in the left, select or unselect to switch between adding and removing the breakpoints